# CKEditor combine inline styles

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

**Steps to reproduce**

I'm working on inline CKEditor. I use font size, line height, & font family plugins. All of these apply to nested spans.

E.g. Text input is - "CKEditor is awesome"

When I applied below commands.

- 1. After added - font family:

```html
<span style='font-family: Arial;'>CKEditor is awesome</span>
```

- 2. After added - font size:

```html
<span style='font-family: Arial;'><span style='font-size: 30px'>CKEditor is awesome</span ></span >
```

- 3. After added - line height:

```html
<span style='font-family: Arial;'><span style='font-size: 30px;'><span style='line-height:50px'>CKEditor is awesome</span ></span ></span >
```

So, All of these added in nested span elements.

**Expected result**

```html
<span style='font-family: Arial;font-size: 30px;line-height:50px'>CKEditor is awesome</span>
```

`OR`

```html
<span class="target_class" style='font-family: Arial;font-size: 30px;line-height:50px'>CKEditor is awesome</span>
```

**Actual result**

```html
<span style='font-family: Arial;'><span style='font-size: 30px;'><span style='line-height:50px'>CKEditor is awesome</span></span></span>
```

**Other details**

To get expected result I use below code snippet to add common class for each span

`CKEditor Version: 4.4.2`

```
config.fontSize_style       = { element : 'span', styles: { 'font-size': '#(size)' }, attributes : { 'data-font-size': '#(size)', 'class' : 'target_class' } };

config.cp_line_height_style = { element : 'span', styles: { 'line-height': '#(size)' }, attributes : { 'data-line-height': '#(size)', 'class' : 'target_class' } };
```